# How can I tell what glowy-ring buffs the enemy team currently has?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-medic, tf2-soldier

To my knowledge, all the following buffs have identical effects of glowing rings around the players' feet, as shown in this picture:

[image: Glowing Rings]

- Deploying a Buff Banner
- Deploying a Battalion's Backup
- Deploying a Concheror
- Playing a medicating melody with the Amputator
- Deploying Ubercharge with a quick-fix

If I could not see the source soldier/medic, what are some tell-tale signs I could easily/instantly recognize their buffs? Additionally, if I saw a buffed soldier coming in from a distance, how can I distinguish what his buff is?

Comment: I think the Concheror buff has a lighter colour, the buff banner gives you glowing weapons, the quick fix pulsates faster.

Comment: The Buff Banner is always a green glow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The auras given by the Soldier's banner buffs have these color schemes:

- RED: golden-yellow glow
- BLU: cyan-aquamarine glow

Whereas the auras given by the Medicating Melody or Quick-Fix ÜberCharge are standard red and blue in color respectively.

A player being buffed by the Buff Banner will have a weapon glowing the same color as the aura, so a RED player for example will have both a golden-yellow aura and a golden-yellow weapon. A player being buffed by the other banners won't have a glowing weapon.

Telling a Battalion's Backup buff from a Concheror buff is more difficult: if you're looking at the Soldier who deployed the banner, he'll be carrying a different flag; see [Retrosaur's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/113764/how-can-i-tell-what-glowy-ring-buffs-the-enemy-team-currently-has/114384#114384) for what the banners look like. However, if he isn't visible, you won't be able to tell which of the two buffs his teammates have received unless you heard the horn, or until you engage them in battle.

The difference between a Medicating Melody and a Quick-Fix ÜberCharge is that the latter will also shower the Medic and his patient with sprinkling healing crosses, not to mention the presence of a healing beam.

From what I've observed, all auras pulsate at the same frequency.

Comment: Note that weapons cannot glow in DX8 mode.

Comment: @Russell Whitchurch: Sorry, I've rolled back your edit. While formatting improvements are generally OK, it's not appropriate to completely replace somebody else's answer with your own writing and formatting. Plus, I do not feel comfortable taking credit for something I didn't write. If you want to post your own answer, please do so.

Comment: @TheAnnoyingPyro If you want, you can reference your answer with my answer, in regards to "I don't believe there's a visual difference between the Backup and the Concheror"

Comment: @Retrosaur: Done.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to other answers here, an easy way to tell which buffs are deployed by Soldiers are the flags that are being deployed.

## Buff Banner:

[image: Buffy the medic slayer]

> The war flag itself – which is **rectangular** and **colored faded yellow**
>   with a **brown starbust design** and moves realistically – remains hidden
>   in the backpack until it is activated, at which point it will appear
>   on a pole mounted to the pack.

## Battalion's Backup:

[image: From BattleBlock Theatre???!]

> ...a tattered **yellow triangular banner**, patched up and reattached in the
>   middle, that is displayed when the buff is active

## The Concheror

[image: toot.jpg]

> A **white**, slightly tattered, **vertical banner flag** with the same **diamond
>   insignia secured onto a pair of bamboo sticks** appears when the banner
>   call is played.

If your computer has higher graphic settings, and you can see enemies from far away, sometimes the horns are a good giveaway, indicated by either a brass trumpet (Buff Banner), a brown horn (Battalion's Backup), or a white Seashell (Concheror).

Answer (score 2):

Though you must look for different cues, each of them has at least one obvious sign that differentiates them from one other.

**Differences between soldier auras and medic auras:**

- Shortly before a soldier deploys any banner, every player (including you) will hear a distinct trumpeting noise. No medic auras have this.
- Soldier auras are always a light golden color (RED team) or light cyan color (BLU team). Medic auras match their team color.

**Differences between each soldier banner:**

- Buff Banner: auras *and* weapons glow. You will also hear a distinct horn for [RED](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/images/f/fc/Buff_banner_horn_red.wav) or [BLU](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/images/c/cb/Buff_banner_horn_blue.wav).
- Battalion's Backup: Only auras surround players without weapon glow. Same horn sound as the Buff Banner.
- Concheror: Only auras surround players, however has a [separate horn sound](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/w/images/a/a4/Concheror_horn.wav) (both teams).

**Differences between each medic aura:**

- Medicating Melody: No healing beam present, and can have multiple targets. Auras are solid red or blue.
- Quick-fix ÜberCharge: Healing beam present, and sprinkling healing crosses are present.